# iOS - Saving Video Inside App

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video

I recently found an answer on stackoverflow of how to store an image inside of an App:

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
} else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
} else {
    ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
}
}
```

How can I store a video that a user chooses from photo/video library and save it inside app? Is it any different? I'm trying to keep track of a list of videos that a user want's to upload and when he/she ready they can upload all those videos to the app's server.

Comment: Why would you save a separate copy of the video? Why not cache the video paths and then upload those originals?

Comment: As Miles Alden said, you probably want to keep track of the movie URL's rather than copy the entire movie.  In your picker delegate, you can get the URL from the info dictionary using the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` key.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll give that a try. I can just use NSUserDefault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i don't really understand your purposes, but you may try using `NSFileManager` in order to just copy a file from one URL to another:

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:mediaURL toURL:outputURL error:&error];
```

If you need to manipulate your movie in some way (i.e. cropping, changing quality), you should be using AVExportSession:

```
+ (void)writeMovieAtURL:(NSURL *)mediaURL
                  toURL:(NSURL *)outputURL
             withQality:(NSInteger)quality
      completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *, NSError *))completion {


    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:mediaURL options:nil];


    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset];
    NSString *exportPreset;

    switch (quality) {
        case 0 : { exportPreset = AVAssetExportPreset1280x720;      } break;
        case 1 : { exportPreset = AVAssetExportPreset640x480;       } break;
        case 2 : { exportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality; } break;
        case 3 : { exportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality;    } break;
    }

    if (nil != exportPreset && [compatiblePresets containsObject:exportPreset]) {
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                  initWithAsset:asset presetName:exportPreset];

        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;

        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

        // set some params to the session

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{                
            switch ([exportSession status]) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {                       
                    completion(outputURL, nil);
                    [exportSession release];
                } break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting : {
                    NSLog(@"Export Waiting");
                } break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting : {
                    NSLog(@"Export Exporting");
                } break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed : {
                    completion(outputURL, [exportSession error]);
                    [exportSession release];
                } break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled : {
                    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Movie export session canceled"
                                                                         forKey:@"ocalizedDescription"];                        
                    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"your.domain" 
                                                         code:123 
                                                     userInfo:userInfo];                        
                    completion(outputURL, error);
                    [exportSession release];
                } break;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```